# how can i verify that CreateToolhelp32Snapshot() is using NtQuerySystemInformation?

Tags: c++, winapi

i read that `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot()`, `EnumProcesses()` and Windows TaskManager are all using the undocumented `NtQuerySystemInformation` function.

is there any way i can verify this? i am looking for a tool that can show me all the under layer api calling that programs do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Monitoring API calls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/961779/monitoring-api-calls) and [Monitoring application calls to DLL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/311268)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a project named [ReactOS](https://www.reactos.org/) which is mostly a reverse engineering of Windows. `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot` and its freinds could be found in the file [`toolhelp.c`](https://github.com/mirror/reactos/blob/master/reactos/dll/win32/kernel32/client/toolhelp.c#L1250):

```
[ReactOS Path]/dll/win32/kernel32/client/toolhelp.c
```

which actually makes a call to `NtQuerySystemInformation` in this chain:

```
CreateToolhelp32Snapshot
  |
TH32CreateSnapshot
  |
NtQuerySystemInformation
```

As for `EnumProcesses` ([`dll/win32/psapi/psapi.c`](https://github.com/mirror/reactos/blob/master/reactos/dll/win32/psapi/psapi.c#L453) and [`lib/epsapi/enum/processes.c`](https://github.com/mirror/reactos/blob/master/reactos/lib/epsapi/enum/processes.c#L152)):

```
EnumProcesses
  |
PsaEnumerateProcesses
  |
PsaEnumerateProcessesAndThreads
  | 
PsaCaptureProcessesAndThreads
  |
NtQuerySystemInformation
```

Or using a disassembler, IDA:

[image: NtQuerySystemInformation references to]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rS6q.png

Comment: ReactOS is, however, a clean room reverse engineering of Windows. So although it strives to implement identical functionality, you cannot assume that it does so exactly the same way as Windows itself. That makes this a partial answer to the question. Indeed, you *can* implement `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot` via `NtQuerySystemInformation`, but that doesn't mean Windows *does*.

Comment: @CodyGray It's possible to use a disassembler, ReactOS would save the time. Any way both functions do call `NtQuerySystemInformation` though the path is different.